# Does View::share pass data to all views of one user or all users?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel documentation about View::share() function:

> Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views
>   that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view
>   facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share
>   within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to
>   the  AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to
>   house them.

I wonder whether all views are all views of all requests (visitors) or all views of one request (one visitor)? What if I want to share user specific data accross all views of only this specific user? (For example, I want to share $name of the user accross all views of the user, I wonder whether the data of user A passed to the views of user B).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your visit a site a new instance for the application is created. Hence for every user it  is a different instance. And data is visible to that particular instance. So doing so won't share data of user A with user B.

Imagine an e-commerce application. Every user who visits the application gets his own cart not of the other users. Any product he adds to the cart is limited to only his cart.